# how to use Map<String, JLabel> with a for loop

Tags: java

It is possible to do this with a for loop?

```
public class MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final Map<String, JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String,JButton>();

    public MainScreen() {
        buttonMap.put("utilaj1", utilaj1);
        buttonMap.put("utilaj2", utilaj2);
        buttonMap.put("utilaj1", utilaj1);
        buttonMap.put("utilaj2", utilaj2);
        //......................
        buttonMap.put("utilaj20", utilaj20);
    }
}
```

something like this:

```
public class MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final Map<String, JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<>();

    public MainScreen() {
        for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
            buttonMap.put("utilaj1", utilaj1);
            buttonMap.put("utilaj"+i, utilaj+i);
        }
    }
}
```

this not works because `utilaj1`...`utilaj20` it's a JButton

Comment: You need to add first all the jbutton in a list

Comment: the problem is that you have variables `utilaj1`...`utilaj20` with numbers in them. Variables with numbers are almost always a massive code smell, you need to use an array.

Comment: Yes but i want to do that with a for loop. if it is possible

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y-Problem.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ... best way to solve the X-Y-Problem is to ask "Why?" several times. So - why do you insist to use a `for-loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by adding all the buttons in a list and then put them in the map like this :

```
private final Map<String,JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String,JButton>();
private List<JButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(utilaj1, ..., utilaj20);

public MainScreen() {
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
        buttonMap.put("utilaj"+i, buttons.get(i));
    }
}
```

But it won’t be easier to use, you can directly work with the List, depends on what you want to do with

Comment: Makes me question whether you even need the map if you already have the array. The map is effectively just doing `X -> X`

Comment: @Michael sure, I think a basic `List` would be sufficient